# Bulk Removing Redundant or Malformed Contact Information on macOS Catalina

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts

A few weeks back I tried Microsoft Outlook on macOS and must have tried syncing my contacts from in there which added a TON of seemingly redundant information into each of almost all of my contacts. The included image has some of that info visible, so that you can see what I mean. What's the best way for us to remove this kind of data? I basically want to scrub my contacts of it.

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be looking to Time Machine for something like this.

Contacts data is in `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/` but I wouldn't know where to begin with unpicking it manually. I'd just restore the entire folder to a date before Outlook.

Comment: Unfortunately this was done a few weeks back or so, so other changes would be lost if I followed that.

Comment: @anonymousacorn - Are we talking hundreds of contacts or dozens?  I suppose you have to pick your poison.

Comment: @Ramhound Maybe a hundred or so contacts, at most. Pick it how?

Comment: @anonymousacorn - What requires less work, fixing your all current contacts, or creating new contacts for the delta between your backup and your current contact list.

Comment: Probably recreating the contacts. Oof. Note taken.